# Is it possible to make a symbolic link of a file in other machine?

Tags: ssh, filesystems, symlink

I have a account in a server and I would like have a symbolic link of some files in my local machine.

How can I do this?

Comment: The only way would be to mount the remote directory somewhere locally.

Comment: I agree with @jw013. Why would you want a symlink on another machine? I see the tag `ssh`, at that point you may want to consider sshfs. Really, you should use a NAS, SAN, or NFS as that is more "permanent".

Answer (score 0):

[It's not possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145636/symlink-from-one-workstation-to-another-without-mount) in general. However, if you happened to want to directly edit files through, e.g., a text-editor, you can use sftp:

When an ssh key has already been copied, you can edit remote files **directly** and **without transfer** by using the filename `sftp://username@hostname/home/myfile.txt`

At least that works in Kate.