# Device major/minor number for remote filesystem

Tags: files, filesystems, mount, devices, sshfs

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145670/48707) states:

> A mounted network share will have a `deviceId` which is why you can
>   create a symlink to a mounted location.

So, if "a mounted network share will have a `deviceId`", files mounted with `sshfs` will have a physical device associated with them, like any other filesystem would do. I mounted a remote directory in the local system (Ubuntu 14.04) with

```
sshfs user@remotehost:/remote/directory /home/local/directory
```

In the output of `mount` of the local system a corresponding line is correctly displayed:

```
user@remotehost:/remote/directory on /home/local/directory type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

For all the files in `/home/local/directory/`, `stat` outputs `Device: 30h/48d`. But neither in `/sys/dev/block`, nor in `/sys/dev/char` there is such a local device with major number 3!

So, what kind of device is it where can I find it in my *local system*?

Comment: "Is said" *by whom*?

Comment: @MichaelHomer [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145670/48707).

Comment: That is a bad answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sshfs` uses [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), the *File System in UserSpace* infrastructure, so it's not associated to a block device at all (and of course not to a character device, either). I don't know how the device number `stats` output is related to that kernel infrastructure, if it is related at all and not just random content.

Comment: I updated my question with a [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145670/48707). Have a look, if it can be useful.

Comment: The question in your link is about *symlinks* (which *do* have real inodes in a real filesystem), not about inodes represented by fuse. So it's completely unrelated, and not useful.

Comment: It states: «a mounted network share will have a `deviceId` which is why you can create a symlink to a mounted location». I think the first part of the sentence is relevant here.

Comment: @BowPark As dirkt explains, the deviceId value is does not identify an actual block device. It's a made-up value to have something in the deviceId field.