# system directories don't appear in "ls" output

Tags: centos, ls

When I `ls` all files in CentOS 7, I get very few directories and there's no bin, no lib etc[image]

What happened here?

Comment: Welcome to U&L! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: See [Why is Linux's filesystem designed as a single directory tree?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93960/80216)

Answer (score 3):

You are executing `ls` in home directory. The current working directory `~` is shown in prompt after hostname (`localhost`). `~` is current user's home directory.

You should run `ls /`, or change directory by `cd /` before running `ls`, if you want to see contents of the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the home of `root`. That explains why you have the `anaconda-ks.cfg`.

To get `ls` by itself to return `bin`, `lib`, `lib64` and so on and so forth, you need to first run one of the following:

`cd /usr`

`cd /`

And the run `ls`.

You can also run one of these:

`ls /`

`ls /usr`

Basically, in CentOS, those directories exist in `/usr` ( there is also a symlink to them in `/`) and not in `/root` which is where you've been running `ls`.